# Proper Quoting of Strings When Executing Remote Commands via SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

My environment is Bash under Debian 8.

```
# Suppose I enter the following value for MY_STRING: TEST$TEST
read -s -p "Enter a string: " MY_STRING

# This commands displays this value: TEST$TEST
echo "$MY_STRING"

# This command displays this value: TEST
ssh root@my-host "echo $MY_STRING"

# How may I cause the above command to display the value "TEST$TEST"?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By quoting it so that the other side receives a fixed string.

```
ssh root@my-host "echo '$MY_STRING'"
```

Since the expansion is done locally the single quotes will not affect it.